# Swipe events not working in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

swipe left and right is not working in my app. My code goes like this

```
    $('#pane').swipeleft(function(e, touch) {
        console.log(" Left Swipe");
                });
    $('#pane').swiperight(function(e, touch) {
        console.log("Right Swipe");
                });
```

It works fine in desktop and Ipad. but not in android. Any android ppl please help. I'm new to android. I got struck for a day.

Comment: Here is someone, who wants to achieve exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833504/simple-swipe-gesture-to-activity-tutorial

Comment: kindly look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19188007/3164682

Comment: what is your develope paltofrm?

Comment: thanks Sarath . but it doesnt make it work. issue still persists

Comment: @KonstantinJäger I dont look for native code. It is something related to javascript event handling